# Any reason why I cannot join a vector of int with a delimeter

Tags: c++, fmt, c++23

Why is the following not possible (something that would work with fmt::join)

```
std::vector<int> dest {1, 2, 3, 4}
auto joined =  dest | std::views::join_with(',');
```

I am compiling with the recent gcc trunk (14.0.1)

Is there no standard function that resembles fmt::join?

It seems that the issue relates to the fact that the vector is of type `int` , changing it to `std::string` would work.

My question is really why the above is not supported while it is when using fmt::join?.. Any prospects regarding supporting fmt::join in the standard library now that we got std::format.

Comment: why do you think its not possible? Compiler errors? Not getting expected results?

Comment: `join_with` works on views of ranges. `std::vector<int>` is not a view **of ranges**.

Comment: You need to convert these integers to string first. [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/18r8e78x8).

Comment: I do imagine it would work when I transform the ints to strings, however, I am wondering why the standard did not support this case natively like fmt::join..

The compiler error is related to the | not being supported which is because the types between the vector and the delimeter differs

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood the question. You wonder _why_ this joining isn't in the standard, not how to accomplish something similar, right?

Comment: Yes, I know it would work if I converted my vector to strings, however I do wonder why such does not wrk in the standard, given fmt::join does. I thought the fmt library (ish) was going to be supported by the stdlib - and I guess fmt:::join is a very popular one

Comment: not everything from `fmt` made it into `format`. I think you are looking for this https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3594.html. Though its from 2013 and I dont know what the status is

Comment: Afaik, `fmt::join` isn't in the standard

Comment: you are looking in the wrong place. `std::views` is ranges library not `format`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The basic reason it isn't supported is type safety.

`join_with` takes one range of elements, and one range specifying a delimiter. It then "flattens" the range of elements, and inserts an instance of the delimiter between each of those elements. The result it produces is a range though. When you iterate over that range, you iterate over elements of some particular type. That type is the type of the elements in your input range (in this case `int`). But the delimiter you've given is a string literal, not an `int`.

We could make this work by creating a type that can hold *either* of the two possible input types though:

```cpp
using element = std::variant<int, std::string>;
```

Now we need two ranges with that as the underlying type, so our result range will be a `std::join_range<element>`. Unfortunately, a single element isn't a range by itself. For the moment, I'm going to "cheat" and use a vector of one element as the delimiter--but that means each item in the input range also has to be a `vector<int>`, not just an `int`. So the monstrosity we get is something like this:

```cpp
    using element = std::variant<int, std::string>;

    std::vector<std::vector<element>> v {{1}, {2}, {3}, {4}};
    std::vector<element> delim{","s};

    auto res = v | std::views::join_with(delim);
```

Now we can join our two ranges, to produce a result view in which each item is an `std::vector<element>`.

Note, however that if you wanted to do something like print these out you'd need to do something like an `std::visit` on each item to sort out whether the item contained in that `std::variant` was a `string` or an `int`, and print it out appropriately.

As to why `fmt::join` was different: `fmt` as designed primarily for printing things (and similar), so it automatically converted *everything* to a string (or at least something string-like), ready to be written to a stream. You didn't need to convert your items to strings, because it did that automatically.